# Phalcon Fatal error: Class 'Phalcon\Mvc\Application' not found in

Tags: php, composer-php, phalcon

I have this file directory:
[image]
When I open this project in browser: Fatal error: Class 'Phalcon\Mvc\Application' not found in...

I read that I have to install composer but when I install composer this errors occure:
[image]

How can I run my project?

My composer.json file consists:

````
    "require": {
        "phalcon/incubator-mailer": "^1.0",
        "smi2/phpclickhouse": "^1.4",
        "hybridauth/hybridauth": "^3.8"
    }
}```
````

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Post just plain or formatted text.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck? If you are facing any error, please share it **in text form**, along with your attempts to resolve that error. Composer usualy provides some hints about what to do

Answer (score 0):

There are in fact two problems.

1. You are missing the phalcon php extension. You can find the instructions on how to install the extension in the [official Phalcon documentation](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/de-de/installation#psr).
2. You need at least php version 7.3 to satisfy the requirements of `smi2/phpclickhouse`. Since php 7.x is EOL since 26th of November 2022, I'd strongly suggest to upgrade to the latest version which currently is php 8.1.

Once you resolved the two problems, `composer install` should run successfully, and the missing classes should be placed in the `vendor` directory.

Comment: Did not help ``` ```

Comment: Problem1
    - Root composer.json requires phalcon/incubator-mailer ^1.0 -> satisfiable by phalcon/incubator-mailer[v1.0.0].
    - phalcon/incubator-mailer v1.0.0 requires ext-phalcon ^4.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's phalcon extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - W:\modules\php\PHP_8.1\php.ini
You can run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI .
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-phalcon` to temporarily ignore  required extensions

Comment: `phalcon/incubator-mailer v1.0.0 requires ext-phalcon ^4.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's phalcon extension. To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files: - W:\modules\php\PHP_8.1\php.ini You can run php --ini in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI` You did not install the phalcon extension yet. See problem 1 of my answer.

Comment: @AzizxonZufarov: Add (Edit in) all information (clarifications etc.) into your question, not as a comment buried under some answer, otherwise Christoph and others aren't able to properly formulate one.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on some of the other comments, Phalcon 4 is NOT compatible with PHP 8.1.  Phalcon 4 requires PHP 7.4.

If you plan on running PHP 8.1, you will need to install Phalcon 5.1.1.

You can find the Phalcon installation documentation on at https://phalcon.io